# Different results between Ruby Digest::MD5.base64digest and PHP base64_encode

Tags: php, ruby, encoding, base64

I didn't work with ruby ever, only with php. And I need help.

I have ruby code which encode string like that:

```
str = '123';
arr = str.bytes
p Digest::MD5.base64digest(arr.pack('C*')) # ICy5YqxZB1uWSwcVLSNLcA==
```

I need to do the same in php, and get the the same result. My example

```
$str = '123';
$bytes = unpack('C*', $str);
$pack = pack('C*', implode(', ', $bytes));
echo base64_encode(md5($pack)); // YzRjYTQyMzhhMGI5MjM4MjBkY2M1MDlhNmY3NTg0OWI=
```

Why the results are different. Thanks for help.

Comment: did you see my answer? hopefully, it helps.

Comment: Yeah, It's helps! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As its unpacking and then repacking the bytes it's not needed, but ill keep the code as-is.

In PHP [pack](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php) requires each array argument to be passed, so you need to re-pack each argument in a loop.

```
<?php
$str = 123;
$bytes = unpack('C*', $str);
$pack = null;
foreach ($bytes as $arg) $pack .= pack('C*', $arg);
```

Or in PHP > 5.6 you can use inline argument unpacking. `...`

```
$str = 123;
$bytes = unpack('C*', $str);
$pack = pack('C*', ...$bytes);
```

Then the last issue is because rubys [base64digest](https://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_392/Digest/Instance/base64digest) maintains the digest state, you also need to use md5's second param [raw_output](http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php#parameter) to do the same.

> If the optional raw_output is set to TRUE, then the md5 digest is
>   instead returned in raw binary format with a length of 16.

```
$str = 123;
echo base64_encode(md5($str, true));
```

So your finished ported code would look like:

```
$str = 123;
$bytes = unpack('C*', $str);
$pack = pack('C*', ...$bytes);
echo base64_encode(md5($pack, true)); // ICy5YqxZB1uWSwcVLSNLcA==
```

Or just.

```
<?php
$str = 123;
echo base64_encode(md5($str, true)); // ICy5YqxZB1uWSwcVLSNLcA==
```

Comment: Sorry for late answer, I trying your code, it's working very well! Thank you a lot!!!

Comment: np, glad to help